# Can a rails app and a subgraph created using The graph protocol share the same postgres db?

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, subgraph, thegraph

Do you know if it’s possible for a rails (or nodejs) app to share the same postgres db as a subgraph that's been created using The graph protocol? Or does the subgraph need a dedicated db? If it does, would a rails app reading from multiple database be a better strategy?

Any pointers you can share would be much appreciated!

Comment: The basic rule is that the database can be shared with anything that can successfully connect to it. If you can successfully build a connect string in both then you can share the database.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help

So I currently have two solutions in mind that I am going to try to implement but I wanted to get some feedback to have a sense of what's better.

1. I run my own The Graph node which will have its own Postgres DB and have a rails app using that same DB. I think I will just need to make sure I use dedicated tables for the subgraph just to be safe.

2. I have two different DB. One for my subgraph and one for my Rails app. and would configure my ORM (ActiveRecord) to fetch data from these two postgres DBs.

Thoughts or resources you can redirect me to?